# How to test a django rest url with query parameter?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

My URL has 'nutritionist' query parameter, in this case, it will get profiles that has nutritionist with id=1

```
/profiles?nutritionist=1
```

When I tried to test this 'filtering' like this:

```
def test_get_user_belonging_to_a_nutritionist(self):
        response = self.client.get("/profiles?nutritionist=1/",secure=True)

        users = CustomUser.objects.filter(nutritionist=1)
        serializer = CustomUserDetailsSerializer(users, many=True)

        self.assertEqual(response.data, serializer.data)
```

The response contains HttpResponsePermanentRedirect object, instead of the normal response

This is my Views.py if it helps

```
class GetProfilesViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CustomUserDetailsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Optionally restricts the returned purchases to a given user,
        by filtering against a `username` query parameter in the URL.
        """
        queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
        nutritionist_id = self.request.query_params.get('nutritionist')
        if nutritionist_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(nutritionist=nutritionist_id)
        return queryset
```

How can I test this case?

Answer (score 1):

Query parameters should be added after `/` and used with `?` began.

When there are multiple query parameters, use `&` concatenation.

So your URL should be written as `/profiles/?nutritionist=1`.

Finally, it is recommended that query filters([django-filter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend)) be used instead of overriding the `get_queryset` method.